# Why is Bluetooth Low Energy not connecting on some devices?

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm quite new to Objective-C programming and I have a problem with my app.
It connects to a device (an electronic board) through a Bluetooth Low Energy interface. My iPad is acting as a Central Manager, and the device it gets the data from acts as a Peripheral.

I use the CoreBluetooth framework.

It connects perfectly when I run the app on my iPad (iOS 7.02), but on any other device it hardly ever succeeds. I tried it in four other devices, all of them with the same iOS (7.02) and they hardly ever connect successfully to the electronic board (they managed to connect in a couple of chances).

I'm lost and don't know where to open a path to find the solution to that problem.

I don't know which other information could be useful to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is the obvious, but worth mentioning. You bluetooth is on and you've scanned and picked up the Smart Device with your Smart Ready device. Given a yes to all of the above it just won't connect? 
Have you ensured that it's not auto connecting to one of your other devices that you've previously connected with? Unless you've made some extraneous adjustments to your smart device's firmware it will only connect to one device at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But no, it does not autoconnect, and it doesn't connect in the other devices even the app is not running in my iPad at the moment (so no chance of autoconnecting).

Comment: Guess it has something to do with the wi-fi network the others were connected to (and my iPad wasn't). It seems like iOS7 doesn't like being connected to some concrete wi-fi operators and performing bluetooth LE connections at the same time...

Comment: Even when all three Wi-Fi bands are severely contested in your area, BLE still has a few frequencies between the bands where it can work. There was a bug where Wi-Fi affected BLE performance on OS X, but it shouldn't happen anymore, especially not on iOS. You may want to file a bugreport on bugreport.apple.com if you have a device that only works when Wi-Fi is disabled.